# Adding to an ArrayList using a TUI

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, tui

I'm implementing a class called "BorrowerTUI" to an existing project for an assignment. I've been trying for hours and I just can't work out how to add to my ArrayList using the TUI. The information that needs to be added is in a class called "Borrower". Here is the constructor:

```
public Borrower(String fName, String lName, String lNumber, int numberOfBooks, 
                String street, String town, String postcode)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    libraryNumber = lNumber;
    noOfBooks = numberOfBooks;         
    address = new Address(street, town, postcode);
}
```

Previously, I added the object to the ArrayList using a different class called "BorrowerList". Here is the method:

```
public void addBorrower(Borrower borrower)
{

   borrowers.add(borrower);
}
```

That works with no problems. Now what I'm trying to do is use a TUI to add the same information to the same ArrayList. Here is the constructor for "BorrowerTUI" and the options the user will have:

```
private BorrowerList borrowerList;
private Scanner myScanner;

public BorrowerTUI()
{
   myScanner = new Scanner (System.in);
   borrowerList = new BorrowerList();
   Borrower borrower;
}

private void displayMenu()
{
    System.out.println("To add a borrower........................[1]");
    System.out.println("To get the total number of borrowers.....[2]");
    System.out.println("To remove a borrower.....................[3]");
    System.out.println("To show all borrowers....................[4]");
    System.out.println("To show a single borrower................[5]");
    System.out.println("To close Borrowers.......................[0]");
}

private void addBorrower()
{
      borrowerList.addBorrower();
}
```

That doesn't work and I have tried to implement other solutions with no joy. I tried something along the lines of:

```
private void addBorrower()
{
  myScanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  borrower = (firstName, lastName);

  System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
  myScanner.nextLine() = firstName;
  System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
  myScanner.nextLine() = lastName;

  borrowerList.add(borrower);            
}
```

That was a bit of guess work as we haven't actually covered this material in class, we're expected to work it out ourselves having briefly touched on TUIs. Hopefully this is enough information, please let me know if you need me to elaborate or provide any additional code.

Comment: You´d need to get the values for the `Borrower` first, then create a local variable of `Borrower` and assign it with a new instance of this class with the given values and call `addBorrower(Borrower)` with this specific variable.

Comment: Please review [the language basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), especially variable declarations (where do you declare them? Where do you use them? Are your variables *fields* or *local variables*?) and assignment statements (the variable to assign to is always on the left, the expression whose value is assigned is always on the right).

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, some sloppy mistakes on my end. I reminded myself of the basics, cheers RealSkeptic and then followed Kevin's instructions and now it's working!